# C#/.NET ResourceManager does not resolve resource from satellite assembly in GAC

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, localization, gac

I am using the ResourceManager in my C#/WPF desktop application to get localized resources (strings mainly). Furthermore, I am using the ResXFileCodeGenerator to generate a class which retrieves the resources in the UICulture.

Now my application installs all of its libraries (except the UI libraries) in the GAC (Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_32).

For each library a LibraryName and LibraryName.resources is installed. My application can either run with a GUI or from the console. There are two solutions for this. The UI application uses the UI libraries and the other only the libraries containing the logic.

With the UI application everything works well. If I set it to English, it shows everything in English. If I set it to another language, it shows everything in that language.

However, the console application shows everything in English, no matter which language is set. When debugging, I can see that the UICulture is set correctly and that it is correctly recognized, but somehow the ResourceManager does not retrieve the localized resource.

When debugging I can also see that the ResourceManager has a field called "_lookedForSatelliteContractVersion". This is set to "false". In the working case it is set to "true".

What can the problem be? Something with the references of the Console solution? Something with the solution settings of the Console solution?